# tuple generics in array vs rest

Tags: typescript, generics, tuples

I'm trying to build a function that can accept an array of functions that are reduced. It does a lot of other stuff, but in essence it's a pipe. I want to use generics to infer the output of the function. For some reason it's not working unless I have the array be a rest parameter.

Extremely simplified example:

```
const pipe = <A, B, C, D>(items: [
  (a: A) => B,
  (b: B) => C,
  (c: C) => D
]): D => {
  return items.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), {} as A & B & C) as D;
};
```

if I call this like so:

```
const result = pipe([
  (a: {}) => ({
    ...a,
    age: 4,
  }),
  (b) => ({
    ...b,
    color: 'blue',
  }),
  (c) => ({
    ...c,
    height: 100,
  }),
]);
```

I get the type `{ height: number }`.

It seems to just lose its train of thought. Although parameter `b` is of type `{ age: number }`, the parameter `c` is of type `{}`.

If I do exactly the same thing but with a rest parameter:

```
const pipe = <A, B, C, D>(...items: [
  (a: A) => B,
  (b: B) => C,
  (c: C) => D
]): D => {
  return items.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), {} as A & B & C) as D;
};
```

I get the type `{ age: number, color: string, height: number }` as expected.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Not sure why this is, inference just seems to give up when inferring the result of the second function. maybe a limitation maybe a bug...